# Understanding IF() statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to update a spreadsheet that was created by an employee that is no longer with the company. I have been successful in decoding and update all but 1 formula.

```
 ROUND(C6,0)*IF($D$3="Y", 42, 1)
```

I understand most of that formula except for two parts. I understand that the first part rounds what ever value is in C6 to the 0 decimal place, then it checks D3 to see if the value is "Y", if it is then it takes the rounded number and multiplies it by 42. What I can not figure out is what that final `1` is for. Can anyone enlighten me on what that last `1` is doing?

Comment: -1 for lack of attempt; an Internet search or use of 'Help' would have been a better use of time than creating this post. +1 for each of the two good answers.

Comment: This is really a poorly written formula.  Better readability like =IF($D$3="Y", Round(C6,0)*42,Round(C6,0))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `IF`, so that if `$D$3` is not equal to `Y`, it will multiply the rounded value of C6 by `1`.

`IF` is used as:

```
=IF(Expression, Evaluate if true, Evaluate if false)
```

The expression is `$D$3="Y"`, the value if true is `42` and that if false is `1`.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete You're welcome! Should you have any question still, let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply applying the multiplicative identity function.

If $d$3 = 'y', scale the rounded value of C6 by 42, other just return the rounded value of C6 itself.